# public void crashes the app after onClick

Tags: java, android

This is the method that gets triggered by `onClick`. After trying to debug it, I found out the error is in line 3 (displayQuantity)

```
public void increment(View view) {
    numberOfCoffees = numberOfCoffees + 1;
    displayQuantity(numberOfCoffees);
    displayPrice(numberOfCoffees * 5);
}
```

My displayQuantity method looks like this:

```
private void displayQuantity(int numberOfCoffees) {
    TextView quantityTextView = findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);
    quantityTextView.setText(numberOfCoffees);
}
```

[image: picture of an app]

Comment: try adding `.toString()` after formatting and see if it solves the issue

Comment: You are on the right way to inspect what is going wrong. If you arrive in one of the `catch` blocks in debug mode, hover your mouse over the `e` variable. That will give you the information which exception occured. You should also see the exception's stacktrace somewhere, likely in logcat.

Comment: @rcs if this was a type issue, the code would not compile. The `format` method seems to return a `String`.

Comment: surprisingly it will compile, every time I pass Int into setText, it complies and crashes at runtime and saw the docs, it returns, as you mentioned, string

Comment: Because TextView accept int. But int has the meaning of int String resource (R.string.myString). You don't have any log error? Would be easier to helpy you. Surely the log point you directly at your error.

Comment: @TeddySmith Thanks for your comment! I added some erros from the log cat, I hope they are helpful.

Comment: @f1sh Thank you for your comment! Sadly I don't know what you mean by catch blocks. 
If I, in debug mode, press Step Into (F7) it brings me to my other methode:

private void displayQuantity(int numberOfCoffees) {
        TextView quantityTextView = findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);
        quantityTextView.setText(numberOfCoffees);
    }

So maybe the real error is here. Maybe becasue I'm using in .setText an integer?

Comment: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xffffffff  this is your problem

Comment: com.example.justjava.MainActivity.displayQuantity(MainActivity.java:73) at com.example.justjava.MainActivity.decrement(MainA

Comment: NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(numberOfCoffees) this stuff surely give an int. But like I said, the method setText from textView witch accept an in argent is for int resource only (R.string.your string)

Comment: String.valueOf(priceTextView.setText(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(numberOfCoffees)) should fix your problem. At least this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error (and the change to the code I made, although I really thought I didn't do any :D )

```
private void displayQuantity(int numberOfCoffees) {
    TextView quantityTextView = findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);
    quantityTextView.setText(numberOfCoffees);
}
```

The error was in line 3. I think its because I used .setText but gave only an int as input. I fixed it like this:

```
private void displayQuantity(int numberOfCoffees) {
    TextView quantityTextView = findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);
    quantityTextView.setText("" + numberOfCoffees);
}
```

Thanks again to @rcs , @f1sh , @TeddySmith for helping me out and pointing me in the right direction.